# If statement where a variable is equal to a special character [Python]

Tags: python

I've made a simple calculator where you can enter unlimited numbers in one operator(i.e. addition) but every time I run it, it gives an error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My own\Desktop\1.py", line 68, in <module>
choose_operation()
  File "C:\Users\My own\Desktop\1.py", line 9, in choose_operation
    addition()
  File "C:\Users\My own\Desktop\1.py", line 26, in addition
    c = input("Number:")
  File "<string>", line 1
    +
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"
```

I only included two functions here which are the function for selecting the operation to be used and the addition function so it would remain short as possible. The problem is: Whenever I tried to put "c == '+'" in the second to the last line, I get the error mentioned above. What I'd like to happen is that when a user inputs '+', it calls the function 'choose_operation' so I could get back to choosing an operation. What went wrong? Here's my code.

```
def choose_operation():
    print "choose operator"
    print "1. Addition"
    print "2. Subtraction"
    print "3. Multiplication"
    print "4. Division"
    choice = input("choice = ")
    if choice == 1:
        addition()
    elif choice == 2:
        subtraction()
    elif choice == 3:
        multiplication()
    elif choice == 4:
        division()
    else:
        print "Select numbers from 1 to 4"
        choose_operation()

def addition():
    a = input("Number:")
    b = input("Number:")
    sum = a + b
    print sum
    while True: #I put this here so it can keep on adding numbers
        c = input("Number:")
        sum = sum + c
        print sum
        if c == '+':
            choose_operation()
```

Comment: `input` function returns a string , you should cast it to int, `choice = int(input)`

Comment: in python 2, use `raw_input()` or switch to python 3.

Comment: @Arman: The OP is using Python 2's `input` function which evaluates the string it receives from stdin, so if you type an integer `input` will return an integer. As you can imagine, this is a [major security hole](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), and it is generally advised to not use Python 2's `input` function on untrusted data.

Comment: Since you are a newcomer to Python (literally :) ), you should _seriously_ consider learning Python 3. Python 2 will not be supported after 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using python 2, using `input` tries to evaluate the entered string.

It may seem convenient when you enter numbers because you can do:

```
a = input("enter number")
```

and `a` is a float, int, whatever you entered.

But when you want to enter a string, (ex: `+`), the pyhton engine evaluates your expression as `+`, hence the error you're experiencing.

So, drop `input()` for python 2 since it has security issues: you can run system commands and delete files, etc...

Python 2:

- you can use `raw_input()` to get the strings (like `+`)
- enter numbers like this: `a = float(raw_input("enter a float"))`

Python 3:

same thing, but use `input` instead of `raw_input` (`input` as we know it with the nasty evaluation has been removed and `raw_input` is now `input`)